# Sending http request and getting error in response : "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Tags: asp.net, xml

I am sending an `xml` message in http request method. The date format which is required is `MM/dd/yyyy`. I sending the value of dob in the required format but still it send me an error of `datetime`. I couldn't figure out why. Moreover I am using an `api` so these are the requirements of `api` to send date time in this format.

```
        CultureInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
        DateTime mydate = new DateTime();
        // yyyy-MM-dd (2016-10-06) recieved from text box
        mydate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateOfBirthTextbox.Text.ToString(),             "yyyy-MM-dd", us);
        String dob = mydate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: Check date format correctly. Seems like the date format doesn't match.

Comment: I have checked it several times required format is MM/dd/yyyy and I am sending date in this format .plus when I send the request again it shows me an error of duplicate entry so this means now it is recognizing the formmat thats why giving me an error of duplicate entry

Answer (score 1):

Try this.....
Parse the DOB using Datetime.ParseExtract and specify the date format.. it will convert string date to proper date format.